# Scrapy - Code review and questions about items, loaders and pipelines

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape a number of site (50+) which are all of a similar nature, but will have slightly different info on each. Ultimately, this will feed into a database but I will also want to export to csv.

So what I am trying to do, is set up a template to use on each website - essentially, setting up all the possible fields to scrape to. However, each field will not be applicable to every website. So in these instances, I want the data to be scraped in the same format as the "perfect site" (the one with all the fields!) just with blanks for those which are not applicable.

Below are my files:

Items.py

```
import scrapy

class ProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    address1 = scrapy.Field()
    address2 = scrapy.Field()
    address3 = scrapy.Field()
    city = scrapy.Field() 
    random1 = scrapy.Field()
    random2 = scrapy.Field()
    random3 = scrapy.Field()
```

Spider.py

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from Projct.items import ProjectItem
from scrapy.http import request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name            = "ENTER NAME"
    allowed_domains = ["ENTER ALLOWED DOMAINS"]
    start_urls      = ["ENTER START URL"]

    def parse(self, response):

        ''' Selectors '''
        name = response.xpath('ENTER XPATH').extract()
        address1 = response.xpath('').extract()
        address2 = response.xpath('').extract()
        address3 = response.xpath('').extract()
        city = response.xpath('').extract()
        random1 = response.xpath('').extract()
        random2 = response.xpath('').extract()
        random3 = response.xpath('').extract()

        ''' Items '''
        html = response.xpath('ENTER ALL HTML XPATH').extract()
        for html in htmls:
            item = ProjectItem()
            item["name"] = name
            item["address1"] = address1
            item["address2"] = address2
            item["address3"] = address3
            item["city"] = city
            item["random1"] = random1
            item["random2"] = random2
            item["random3"] = random3
            yield item
```

The three main questions I have at the moment:

1. Is this a correct/efficient way to set up my spiders?
2. How can I handle blank values? I.e. if any of the values are not on a
   website I am scraping, how can I have place holder for it with no
   value in it?
3. How can I implement loaders and pipelines? I have read the docs, but am not sure where to put it in my code?

Hopefully, that makes sense and any other general comment on this would be appreciated!

Comment: For code review, [head down here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: @Maverick did you finally find an answer? Could you please your experience?